# Random Forest Output

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest

so I am looking at a supervised, binary prediction problem. Dataframe is mostly categorical which I one-hot encoded. I handled all missing values, NaN, and infinite values.
The dataframe (df) has 2 numerical features and the rest categorical (one-hot encoded). Reminder the dependent variable is binary.

```
dataset_target = df[['dependent_var']].values
dataset_target = pd.DataFrame(dataset_target)
dataset_target.columns=['dependent_var']

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
# Train the classifier
regressor.fit(df, dataset_target.values)

# Print the name and gini importance of each feature
for feature in  regressor.feature_importances_:
    print(feature)
```

The model is supposed to help me select the most important features, it is running however with very unsatisfying results (only 0 and one 1) which I don't even understand and thus don't know what to change on my input.

this is my first prediction project at my internship as a DA, very glad about any help.

This is a snipplet of the output of the randomForrest:

[image]

Comment: Are the classes evenly distributed? E.g 50/50?

If the data is unbalanced, classifiers tend to predict only 1 class

Comment: Did you drop your dependent variable from your features DataFrame ? It seems like you might be predicting dependent variable from dependent variable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider providing a reproducible version of your problem. Based your snippet it looks like you are including your dependent variable as a predictor.

Comment: @RobertWilson thanks for the heads up I will do so in future posts. I explicitly ditched the dependent variable form the predictor dataframe. And it still gives me the same results

Comment: @CharlesBiwer. I am not sure how you have the same results. If you have removed a predictor then you should have one less element in feature importance